# How to store found data when starting script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have currently written a script where I am doing a sort of monitoring on my own web API. The point of my script is that I want to make a sort of monitor where I check every hour to see if there is a new data that has been applied into my API and whenever there is a new data then I would like it to print out.

```py
class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, url: str) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.stored_id: set = set()

    def doRequest(self) -> None:
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get(
                    self.url,
                    timeout=12,
                )

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    parser = response.json()
                    if parser.get('configurations', {}):
                        for configuration in parser['configurations']:
                            if configuration['configuration']['id'] not in self.stored_id
                                upload_to_discord({
                                    'art-number': configuration['art'],
                                     ...
                                })
                                self.stored_id.add(configuration['configuration']['id'])

                time.sleep(3600)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

However my problem is that whenever I run this script, It will always print out to my discord (`upload_to_discord(dict)`) and that means whenever I restart the script, it will always print it out. I wonder how I can skip the first iteration and instead of printing out in the first loop, it should instead store the found data and then after the first iteration it will start to "monitor" to see if there has been aynthing added and print out whenever there is a new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your case you only want to 'not receive' the first iteration and receive all the following ones, you can have a dummy variable `cnt = False` in the beginning of the `while loop` that becomes `True` after the first check. And include this condition in your `if statement`. As shown below:

```
class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, url: str) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.stored_id: set = set()

    def doRequest(self) -> None:
        cnt = False
        
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get(
                    self.url,
                    timeout=12,
                )

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    parser = response.json()
                    if parser.get('configurations', {}):
                        for configuration in parser['configurations']:
                            if (configuration['configuration']['id'] not in self.stored_id) and (cnt):
                                upload_to_discord({
                                    'art-number': configuration['art']
                                    ...
                                })
                                self.stored_id.add(configuration['configuration']['id'])
                                cnt = True
                            else:
                                cnt = True

                time.sleep(3600)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: Dont quite if I follow, tried to do what you said but was not able to.

Comment: I have edited my answer, maybe its clearer?

Comment: Appreciate that. this gave me a another solution as I could simple just use true false instead of count too

Comment: glad it helped! I have edited my answer with the `cnt = False` and then `cnt = True` option.